# how to run python files on my red hat server?

Tags: python, linux, sh, redhat

I tryed to use the sh command but i always get command not found in line x errors. I am using a Red Hat enterprise and i am opening a Nagios plugin programmed with python.

Error: check_fileage.py: line 3: import: command not found

Comment: Does the file have a shebang? Have you tried `python check_fileage.py`?

Comment: Try looking at any tutorial.

Comment: Executable text files in Linux are _assumed_ to be shell if they do not have what's called a "shebang", that directs the OS to use some other interpreter. You need `#! /usr/bin/env python` (optionally `python2.7` or `python3` etc) on the very first line in order to cause Linux to use Python to execute that script.

Comment: Im pretty new to linux but python check_fileage.py helped me out thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `python pythonFile.py` from your bash shell i.e. from the terminal